# Google visualization undefined for setOnLoadCallback

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, undefined

I am using Google Geocharts and following Google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=en) to setup a chart like this:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

 ...
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a1);
  var options = {};

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('div_geochart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

array **a1** is defined globally. The script include lines are present in the header. The problem is, sometimes, I get an error saying:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined`

and the chart doesn't load. The real problem is that it's hard to pinpoint the problem since it doesn't happen always. It seems that sometimes the google.visualization hasn't as yet been set up? But isn't the whole point of calling *drawRegionsMap* using *setOnLoadCallback* that, it will be called after google.visualization has been successfully set up?

I did try changing the location of the *setOnLoadCallback* lines as mentioned here: [Google Visualization - TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined [Chrome specific]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491461/google-visualization-typeerror-cannot-read-property-datatable-of-undefined). I also put those 2 lines in the `<head>` section of the page but the error still occurs sometimes (tested in Chrome and IE).

Could someone give me pointers as to how to avoid getting this error?

Comment: no. this is the only place where *drawRegionsMap* is called from. nothing more here. 'a1' is simply defined as an array at the top of the javacript starting block as: `var a1 = [['Countries', 'Popularity'], ['US', '1']];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that google.setOnLoadCallback is different from google.**charts**.setOnLoadCallback.  If you use google.charts.load() you need to also use google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(). They go together.

Furthermore, since you are using the GeoChart, you probably still need to load the jsapi loader, which is used to load the geocoding data via Google Maps. This is no longer true, however, for the latest version, but still applies if you are using an older version. So your document should look something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSomeGeoChart);
      function drawSomeGeoChart() {
         ...
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is relevant though. Yes I am including the *jsapi* loader as I mentioned and I am using google.seOnLoadCallback, not the other (as in the google documentation I cited)

Comment: Sujay, it's relevant because you're using google.charts.load and not google.load. If you were using google.load you should use google.setOnLoadCallback. However, in your example, you're using google.charts.load, therefore you should be using google.charts.setOnLoadCallback.

Comment: The documentation now *does* say to use google.charts.setOnLoadCallback().  And how you call your function to draw charts is very relevant because it won't work reliably if you don't do it correctly.  Note that if google.setOnLoadCallback is defined (which it will be since you *also* need to load the jsapi loader for the GeoChart, which will define google.setOnLoadCallback) then your callback will be called as soon as any other package loaded by google.load() is finished.  Maybe you would prefer to use the 'callback' property in the google.charts.load() call.

Comment: @SergeyG and  dlaliberte, yes you're right, my mistake. I was mixing them up. I will use `google.charts.function()` in both places and report back.

Comment: @SergeyG and dlaliberte thank you. I changed the lines based on your instructions and it doesn't seem to give the intermittent load problems anymore. cheers.

Comment: do you guys know how to make this work with phantomjs? its driving me crazy

Comment: Turns out if you use `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawSomeGeoChart() );` rather than `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawSomeGeoChart );` you will get the same issue. Not related to THIS issue, but I wanted to record it here for others. The reason being that drawSomeGeoChart() invokes the function immediately, rather than just referencing which function to call once everything is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I typically wait for the `load` event, before loading google.
You can also define the `callback` function, within the `google.charts.load` statement.

```js
var a1 = [
  ['Country', 'Popularity'],
  ['Germany', 200],
  ['United States', 300],
  ['Brazil', 400],
  ['Canada', 500],
  ['France', 600],
  ['RU', 700]
];

// wait for page to load
window.addEventListener('load', loadGoogle, false);

function loadGoogle() {
  // define callback in load statement
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart'], 'callback': drawRegionsMap});
}

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a1);
  var options = {};
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('div_geochart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="div_geochart"></div>
```

Comment: Occasionally, I've seen where loading Google takes longer than it should, but if you wait on the DOM to load, there shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: How is this diffferent from *setOnLoadCallback*? shouldn't the implementation of *setOnLoadCallback* do exactly this? This is what the docs say: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide?hl=en (scroll down to the 'Calling the onLoad handler' section)

Comment: The sporadic timing problem with *setOnLoadCallback* has been reported here as well https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1690. I haven't really found any real fix as yet.

Comment: although it _shouldn't_ be any different, with [dynamic loading](https://developers.google.com/loader/#dynamic-loading), I'm in charge of when stuff happens...

Comment: very nice structure!

Answer (score 0):

In the off-chance someone has the same issue as I had: build in a small delay using `setTimeout()`

For some reason the callback function wasn't doing it's job when I combined the `loader.js` VueJS. After some digging and building in the delay - VOILA! A map :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround:
Add `<script>` tag in the head section and use "defer" to it.

```
<head>
  <script defer async=false src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script defer  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
```