# Using "google.visualization.*" objects in <google-chart> web component in Polymer

Tags: polymer, google-visualization

Is it possible to use core google chart objects (like DataTable or events) from package **google.visualization.*** in Google Polymer component?

I have a webservice returning JSON data and I want to convert it into DataTable.  The error message I get is "Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined"

From this post [Google Visualization - TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined [Chrome specific]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491461/google-visualization-typeerror-cannot-read-property-datatable-of-undefined) I understand that it might be a script loading issue but how can I control the way google-chart scripts are loaded in Polymer?

My Custom Polymer event is below

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html">

<dom-module id="dash-chart">
 <template>
  <style type="text/css">
      
        .google-chart-style {
       width: 100%;
       height: 90%;
      }

      .google-chart-class {
       width:100%;
       height:90%;
        }

     </style>
  <iron-ajax
    auto
    url={{url}}
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse">
  </iron-ajax>
  
  <google-chart 
    class="google-chart-class"
    id="myChart"
    type={{type}}
    options={{options}}>
  </google-chart>

 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "dash-chart",
   properties : {
    url: String,
    type: String,
    options: Object,
    data: Array,
    xaxis: Array,
    yaxis: Array,
    fields: Array
   },
   
   convertResultsToDatatable: function(response) {

    console.log(response);
    //DataTable object
    var objDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    objDataTable.addColumn(this.xaxis[1], this.xaxis[2]);
    objDataTable.addColumn(this.yaxis[1], this.yaxis[2]);

    var afterConversionToDatatable = [[]];
    for(var index in response) {
        var objVal = response[index];
        var arr = [];        
        for(var key in objVal) {

         if(key === this.xaxis[0]) {
          if(this.xaxis[1] === 'number') {
           arr.push(parseInt(objVal[key]));
          } else {
           arr.push(objVal[key]);
          }
         } else if (key === this.yaxis[0]) {
          if(this.yaxis[1] === 'number') {
           arr.push(parseInt(objVal[key]));
          } else {
           arr.push(objVal[key]);
          }
         }

        }
        
        afterConversionToDatatable[index] = arr;
    }

    console.log(afterConversionToDatatable);
    objDataTable.addRows(afterConversionToDatatable);

    return objDataTable;
   },

   handleResponse: function(data) {
    var rootKey;
    var jsonResult = data.detail.response;
    for(var prop in jsonResult) {
     rootKey = prop;
    }

    //Done so that we do not need to hard code the root object (which changes based with every roxie query)
    var resultNode = jsonResult[rootKey].Results.result_1.Row;
    this.data = this.convertResultsToDatatable(resultNode);
 
   }
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: @WhiteHat Polymer's google-chart element internally loads the loader.js file when we try to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work. The first thing to understand is that you can use any class from **google.visualization.*** package once the library has been completely loaded. In my case, the library would load correctly if the `<iron-ajax>` call took more than 5 seconds to complete. If it was anything less than I would get the error: **"Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined"**.

In order to fix this loading issue, I had to write an Observer method which is guaranteed to be called only after property had been set. The key was to call the Observer with `<iron-ajax>` response and google-chart's `type` property set.

Please note that, I tried using polymer lifecycle methods(ready, attached, attributeChanged) and setting the `<iron-ajax>` call to `auto`, but it didn't work.

In my example I am setting the `google-chart` properties from another custom polymer component.

```
<dom-module id="poly-chart">
<template>
    <style type="text/css">
        :host {
            --overlay-opacity
            --overlay-zindex
            --overlay-display
        }

        .google-chart-class {
            width:100%;
            height:90%;
            opacity: var(--overlay-opacity, 1);
            z-index: var(--overlay-zindex);
        }

    </style>
        <iron-ajax
            id={{id}}_ajx
            url={{url}}
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="handleResponse">
        </iron-ajax>

        <google-chart 
            class="google-chart-class"
            id={{id}}
            type={{type}}
            options={{options}}
            on-google-chart-ready='chartLoaded'>
        </google-chart>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "poly-chart",
        properties : {
            id: String,
            url: String,
            type: String,
            options: Object,
            fields: Array,
            inputparams: String,
            ajaxResponse: Object
        },

        observers: [
         'ajaxCall(id, url, inputparams)', 
         'afterAjaxResponse(type, ajaxResponse, fields, id)'],

        ajaxCall: function(id, url, inputparams){
            var ajx = document.querySelector('iron-ajax#'+id+"_ajx");
            ajx.generateRequest();
        },

        handleResponse: function(data) {
            var rootKey;
            var jsonResult = data.detail.response;
            for(var prop in jsonResult) {
                rootKey = prop;
            }

            var resultNode = jsonResult[rootKey].Results.result_1.Row;
            if(resultNode.length === 0) {
                this.loading = false;
            }

            this.ajaxResponse = resultNode;
        },

        afterAjaxResponse: function(chartType,ajaxResponse, fields, id) {
            var loader = document.querySelector('#loader');
            loader.dataTable(null)
                  .then(dt => {
                    return dt;
                  })
                  .then(function(dt){
                    fields.forEach(function(element) {
                        dt.addColumn(element.type, element.label);
                    });

                    var dtRows = convertTo2DArray(ajaxResponse,  getFields(fields));
                    dt.addRows(dtRows);
                    var gc = document.querySelector('google-chart#'+id);
                    gc.data = dt;

                  })
                  .catch(function(error){
                    console.error(error);
                  });
        }

    });
</script>
```

The calling Polymer element looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="poly-widget">
<template>
    <style>
        .widgetHolderDiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>
    <div class="widgetHolderDiv">
        <poly-header title={{title}}></poly-header>
        <poly-chart id={{id}}
                    type={{type}}
                    url={{url}}
                    options={{options}}
                    fields={{fields}}
                    inputparams={{inputparams}}>
        </poly-chart>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
        is: "poly-widget",
        properties: {
            id: String,
            title: String,
            url: String,
            type: String,
            options: Object,
            fields: Array,
            inputparams: String
        }
    });
</script>
```

**FYI:** Here is the link to the question that I had created with google-chart development team on github https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues/182 which has some insights. Hope this helps.